# Continuous function in order topology

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

I have to prove that for every $ \alpha$ in $[0, \Omega)$, there exists a continuous function $f$ from $[0, \Omega)$ to $\mathbb R$ such that the pre-image of $0$ is $\{α\}$.

I really have no idea how to start and would really appreciate just a hint, please don't post the complete answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=\beta+1$ for some $\beta<\Omega$, then $\alpha$ is an isolated point, and you can actually choose $f$ so that its range is $\{0,1\}$. Otherwise, let $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence with limit $\alpha$, and consider making $f$ constant on the clopen intervals $(\alpha_n,\alpha_{n+1}]$.

**Added:** For example, have $f$ send the entire interval $(\alpha_n,\alpha_{n+1}]$ to $-2^{-n}$. To simplify matters, you can send $[0,\alpha_0]$ as well as $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$ to $-1$. Of course $f(\alpha)=0$, so you have only to decide where to send the clopen set $(\alpha,\Omega)$.

Comment: I see why if α=0 or α=β+1 then I can give a function to work, and I can prove it is continuous; buy for α a limit point, I don't see why this function will be continuous.

Comment: @416256: I intentionally gave a fairly minimal hint, since you stressed that you didn’t want a complete solution, but I can add to it without giving the whole game away. Try sending the interval $(\alpha_n,\alpha_{n+1}]$ to $-2^{-n}$. To simplify matters, you can take $\alpha_0=0$ and also set $f(0)=-1$. Then you just have to see what to do with $(\alpha,\Omega)$.